# add row to database django

Tags: python, html, django, database

i have a project for managing students
i can read or edit rows of my database , but i can't **add new data** to it and i don't have any idea ..... some help :(

**html** :

```
<form action="/school_manager/students/add/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="add_first_name">First Name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_first_name" id="add_first_name" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Add"/>
```

there is a html form with a simple text field to add a 'first_name'
for editing the database

it's my **view.py** and worked for me for edit a row's field :

```
def update_student_detail(request, student_id):
    list = get_object_or_404 ( student, pk=student_id)
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        list.First_Name = request.POST.get('update_first_name')
    list.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/school_manager/students/' + student_id)
```

now , what is the way to add data to database ????

thanks

Comment: url(r'^students/add/$',views.add_student,name='Add Student') @shang-wang

Comment: I would suggest creating a form to do this. It's a lot easier for you to create `student` without spending time coding your front end form and back end save logic. Take a look at django model form, it's really straight forward. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: i see that documentation but i can't understand anything @shang-wang

Comment: You can try to google django form examples to help you understand it better. For example the first result I searched be: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_student = student(First_Name = request.POST.get('add_first_name'))
new_student.save()
```

Comment: i think it's true , i have not error for first_name anymore .... wait to complete for other fields

Comment: this code worked .... but clear old rows and add new one  .... i want to just add a new row while keeping the olds

Answer (score 4):

if want to check existing row before creating new one

You Should Use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). It returns tuple

e.g:

```
created_obj = Something.objects.get_or_create(name='ABC',Address="XYZ")
```

Comment: so , this code check for existing tuples and if the new isn't exist , create it ???? @mushahid-khan

Comment: Yeah !!!  If an object is found, get_or_create() returns a tuple of that object and False.   If an object is not found, get_or_create() will instantiate and save a new object, returning a tuple of the new object and True.

Comment: thank you man ... i solved my problem using python forms @mushahid-khan